# Can't connect to EC2 instance (apache/http)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache2

I can't for the life of me connect to my EC2 instance over the web. I know there are six million posts about this already, but they all seem to be resolved the same ways.. but won't work for me.

**What I have tried**

- Enabling relevant inbound (and outbound) traffic in security groups
- Accepting all TCP traffic on port 80 via iptables
- Updating /etc/apache2/ports.conf listen line to "Listen 0.0.0.0:80"
- Restarting apache / EC2 instance between each and every step
- Checking the 000 virtual host conf file - it's listening on port 80

**What I *can* do**

- wget localhost - returns the apache2 landing page (so the web server definitely works
- Ping the instance after setting up ICMP equivalent settings in Security groups - so I'm almost positive Security Groups ain't the problem

Is there anything else I can try?

---

In response to comments..

- traceroute doesn't respond, but "sudo traceroute -T hostname" returns the correct FQDN and IP address
- I haven't modified my network ACL (at least knowlingly), and AFAIK it defaults to allow all inbound/outbound traffic
- My security group inbound rules are as follows:

```
HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
HTTP TCP 80 ::/0
```

- And I have no security group outbound rules
- I haven't set up anything related to VPC, so everything should be default!

Comment: What are the results of `traceroute host` and `tcptraceroute host 80` ?

Comment: Checked Network ACLs? Is it in a public subnet connected to an internet gateway? There are probably quite a few ways this could happen, usually easy to figure out with access, but you haven't given any information about your setup so help here will be limited.

Comment: You mention "relevant outbound traffic in security group" What have you changed? For Outbound, you should allow all traffic unless you have a specific reason to change this.

Comment: I have updated the post with all info requested

Comment: Add ICMP to your security group to allow ping / traceroute. Would be interesting to see how far it gets. I can ping / traceroute my AWS server, given I have ICMP open to my IP. If you share your IP / domain someone might be able to see a problem.

Comment: I can ping, traceroute, and connect to it with http. Your problem is likely client side with your PC or network.

Comment: @Cathal traceroute uses UDP by default on Linux. Use the -I flag for ICMP.

Comment: That's weird.. Waking up this morning to your message, and everything's working fine. Do you know if any of the changes I mentioned take some time to propagate? And thank you for your help!

Comment: Ugh Chrome problems.. Should have checked Firefox before creating this thread..